# User supposedly not in sudoers file, but already is

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sudoers

I wanted to give `user` sudo privileges. I added `user` to the admin group:
`usermod -a -G admin user`

Then I used visudo to check if admin users had been set to receive sudo privileges. I uncommented the line `admin ALL=(ALL) ALL`.

It didn't work.

sudoers file:

```
Defaults        env_reset  
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL  
admin   ALL=(ALL) ALL  
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the relevant sections of your sudoers file?

Re-posted from the comment below:

> **[edit]admin should be %admin - Percent signs are used for groups, you could have also just added the user to be in the sudo group
>   [/edit]**

One quick thing to try is to run grpconv from a root terminal, be it by

> su -c'grpconv'

from a non-root terminal

or actually loggin in as root and entering

> grpconv

Comment: admin should be %admin - Percent signs are used for groups, you could have also just added the user to be in the sudo group